# How to connect value from custom properties to value of object's translate/rotation/scale

Tags: node-editor, transforms, constraints

Sorry I'm new to Blender, came from Maya. Let's say I want to move object A via changing value from object B's custom properties, how can I do it in Blender?

In Maya, there's something called connection editor where basically I can take value from a custom properties/attribute to a translate/rotation/scale or just anything else that able to read said value. I wonder if there's anything like it in Blender or at least nodes for it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

Sure. You can drive the values directly.

1. Create your custom property (I used a cube)
2. *RMB on the value > Copy as New Driver*
3. Target the other object (I used a Cone)  and *RMB > Paste Driver*

[image]

Comment: dammnn huge thanks mann. Looks like drive keys are more versatile in Blender than Maya

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

**Drivers**

[image]

Right click on any animatable property and can add a driver.

By way of example have added a driver to Cone's X location, using a custom property on the "Cone".

- Copy data path from the custom property. In this case the prop named "prop" has datapath `'["prop"]'` which is copied to clipboard.
- Add / Edit Driver. Make a single property variable and use the cone object
- Paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> the previously copied path into field.

Now the cone moves in x direction via the value of the custom property "prop"

**Use self.**

[image]

Note, since the prop and the driver both belong to the cone object, could instead enable the "use self" option and make the driver expression

```
self["prop"]
```

removing the need to set up any driver variables.

Comment: Note that to use "self" in driver expression you must enable "Auto Run Python Scripts" in the Save/Load panel of the preferences